# Binomial count data: interpretation of result of GLMER

Tags: categorical-data, lme4-nlme

I am modeling the proportion of scoring rate of Oneill. I mean to see if Oneill has an unstable scoring rate via GLMM. The formula I desired to use is

$Logit(\pi_i)= \alpha+u_i $, i = 1,2,3,...,N=23

$\pi_i$ is the proportion of score rate in each play and $u_i$ follows N(0,$\sigma^2$), $u_i$ is play-specific random effect.

here is the code I'm using.

```
library(lme4)
shoot <- c(5,11,14,12,7,10,14,15,12,4,27,17,12,9,12,10,12,6,39,13,17,6,12)
score <- c(4,5,5,5,2,7,6,9,4,1,13,5,6,9,7,3,8,1,18,3,10,1,3)
prop <- score/shoot
oneil <- data.frame(shoot=shoot,score=score,prop=prop,play=as.factor(seq(1,length.out=length(shoot))))
#oneil <- data.frame(shoot=shoot,score=score,prop=prop,play=as.factor(rep(c(1,2),length.out=length(shoot))))
m_fit <- glm(prop~1,data=oneil,family=binomial(logit))
summary(m_fit)

glmm_fit <- glmer(prop~1+(1 | play),family = binomial(logit),data=oneil)
summary(glmm_fit)
```

My question is about the result.

```
> summary(glmm_fit)
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) [
glmerMod]
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: prop ~ 1 + (1 | play)
   Data: oneil

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    32.3     34.5    -14.1     28.3       21 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.29922 -0.03136  0.26998  0.61165  1.51187 

Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 play   (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 23, groups:  play, 23

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)  -0.8267     0.4532  -1.824   0.0681 .
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

The variance in the random effect is zero! However, It shouldn't be true because he has an unstable scoring rate actually. So the variance should be large here. So where is wrong with the result or my interpretation here?

Thank you!

Comment: Number of obs 23, groups 23 (as it shows)

Comment: @mdewey This random effect is play-specific. So $u_i$ are i.i.d. I've tried to have one group for 23 obs, but it seems glmer does not allow that. So how should I realise what I mean to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out by myself. When it comes to count data, you have to designate number of trails(which is shoot in my case) in each observation. So I should have:

```
glmm_fit <- glmer(prop~1+(1 | play),family = binomial(logit),weights=shoot,data=oneil)
```

Then everything will be fine. Detailed reason should come from the fitting details of this model, which is out of my range here. That's it.